# Client Side Errors for Office.context.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, error-code

What are the client side errors to be aware of when calling getUserIdentityTokenAsync.

```
Office.context.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync(function cb(result) {
        if (result.status === "succeeded") {
            var token = asyncResult.value;
        } else {
            //What do i expect here?
        }
    });
```

I cannot see any information on this in the documentation. Where am i not looking? On the other hand Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync has documented error codes. Is there something similar for  getUserIdentityTokenAsync?

Answer (score 1):

The errors from this API are likely to be network or web service errors, and other than retrying, there's not much the addin can specifically do.  The suggestion is to retry a few times, with exponential delay between retries (10s, 1 min, 5 min).